# Uploading Python module as AWS Lambda Layer

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am looking to upload the Python module `Shapely` as a layer for my AWS Lambda.
To do this, I have done these steps

```
mkdir folder
cd folder
virtualenv --python=python3.6 v-env 
source ./v-env/bin/activate
pip3 install shapely
deactivate
mkdir shapely
cd shapely 
cp -r ../v-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/* .
cd ..
zip -r shapely.zip shapely
aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name shapely --zip-file fileb://shapely.zip --compatible-runtimes python3.6
```

The layer has successfully uploaded and I've added it to my Lambda but when I try and run it, I get the error `No module named 'shapely'`

I'm stuck as to where I've gone wrong as during the publishing of the layer I got no errors. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Try naming the folder `python` instead of `shapely`

Comment: yes that worked! Thank you. Can I just ask why the folder name caused the issue?

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the folder name `shapely` would not work since according to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path), you should either name it `python` or `python/lib/python<version_number>/site-packages`

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of this - but great to know for future reference